# Can my Web Server Issue a Client Rest Request to another REST Server

Tags: rest, http, server

I have a web server that handles configuration set-up for various IO devices.  I need to get some data from a REST server that is running on a different server.  Can that web server code issue a client REST GET command to a REST server running on a different server?  I tried it but I get a http 500 error.  The server code is failing on the REST server request code.

Comment: This isn't a great SO question as it stands, because it lacks detail. But in general, the answer is yes. Your program is acting in the client role, and as such, is the same as any other client, be it a browser or any other piece of software.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  The problem I was having was associated with my client accessing the REST server with a self-signed certificate.  The client request was blowing up because of the inability to validate the certificate.  I initially thought it might be associated with the client request coming from within the web server.  I fixed the certificate validation in the client and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing out this question.  Yes, your server can issue http requests to other services.  I was having another problem with a self-signed certificate and the error made it look like their was a problem with my http request service.